# DataTables - Map Data and correcting table layout

Tags: ajax, django, datatables, bootstrap-4

I am integrating the DataTables in Django 2.1. But the table is broken and I can not map the data sent by the server to JS.

[image: DataTable Image - Broken Layout]

This is my configuration JS:

```
<!-- Bootstrap CSS Section -->
<link href="{% static 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css' %}" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="{% static 'datatables.net-bs4/css/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.css' %}" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript-->
<script src="{% static 'jquery/dist/jquery.min.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js' %}"></script>
<!-- Datatables plugin JavaScript-->
<script src="{% static 'datatables.net/js/jquery.dataTables.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'datatables.net-bs4/js/dataTables.bootstrap4.js' %}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#user-datatable').DataTable({
        language: {
            "sEmptyTable": "Nenhum registro encontrado",
            "sInfo": "Mostrando de _START_ até _END_ de _TOTAL_ registros",
            "sInfoEmpty": "Mostrando 0 até 0 de 0 registros",
            "sInfoFiltered": "(Filtrados de _MAX_ registros)",
            "sInfoPostFix": "",
            "sInfoThousands": ".",
            "sLengthMenu": "_MENU_ Resultados por página",
            "sLoadingRecords": "Carregando...",
            "sProcessing": "Processando...",
            "sZeroRecords": "Nenhum registro encontrado",
            "sSearch": "Pesquisar",
            "oPaginate": {
                "sNext": "Próximo",
                "sPrevious": "Anterior",
                "sFirst": "Primeiro",
                "sLast": "Último"
            },
            "oAria": {
                "sSortAscending": ": Ordenar colunas de forma ascendente",
                "sSortDescending": ": Ordenar colunas de forma descendente"
            }
        },
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "ajax": {
            "url": "{% url 'authentication:get_users' %}",
            "type": "GET",
            "dataSrc": ""
        },
        "columns": [
            {"data": 'name'},
            {"data": "email"},
            {"data": "last_login"},
            {"data": "is_active"},
        ]
    });
});
</script>
```

My Views.py code:

```
@login_required
def get_users(request):
    object_list = CustomUser.objects.all()
    data = serializers.serialize('json', object_list)
    return JsonResponse(data, safe=False)
```

This is the Json generated by Views.py that I can see in Firefox:

```
[
{
"model": "authentication.customuser", 
"pk": 1, 
"fields": 
        {"password": "1234", 
        "last_login": "2018-09-03T15:17:29.007Z", 
        "is_superuser": true, 
        "name": "John", 
        "username": "john", 
        "email": "john@mail.com", 
        "is_staff": true, 
        "is_active": true, 
        "groups": [], 
        "user_permissions": []}
        }, 
{
"model": "authentication.customuser", 
"pk": 2, 
"fields": 
        {"password": "12345", 
        "is_superuser": false, 
        "name": "Ana", 
        "username": "ana", 
        "email": "ana@mail.com", 
        "is_staff": false, 
        "is_active": true, 
        "groups": [], 
        "user_permissions": []}
        }, 
 }
 ]
```

How do I map this data in JS DataTable to display correctly in columns?

Answer (score 0):

Besides you have a closing curly brace too many (assume it is a copy paste error) you do not need any mapping or change to the JSON. It is nicely sectioned in an array of `fields`. The only concern is `last_login` which seem to be left out occasionally, `defaultContent` solves that :

```
columns: [
  { data: 'fields.name'},
  { data: 'fields.email'},
  { data: 'fields.last_login', defaultContent: ''},
  { data: 'fields.is_active'}    
]
```

Set `"serverSide": false`, your script does not support serverside processing anyway. If you must have serverside processing https://github.com/izimobil/django-rest-framework-datatables seems to support at least django 2.0.

Comment: I set "serverSide" to false and put "fields.name", etc, but got this error:

"DataTables warning: table id=user-datatable - Requested unknown parameter 'fields.name' for row 0, column 0. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/4"

Comment: @DevPython, unless the returned JSON is different than described it should work, see this mockup  -> http://jsfiddle.net/puw1yLsk/

Comment: Got it! I can already display the data in the table, but it continues with the broken layout as shown in the post image. Any idea what that might be?

Comment: @DevPython, you do have `serverSide: false`? The image looks like `serverSide: true` when the serverSide script return inadequate info; How does the HTML / table markup look like?

Comment: I remove "serverSide" from JS. This is my table html:
https://pastebin.com/WtAUAM6E

Comment: @DevPython, If I take your markup and all your JS above, except the new column definition it works -> http://jsfiddle.net/yaL3jpf9/ are you sure it is not some kind of cache problem?

Comment: The problem persists, it was not a problem with the cache. That's my table, it's still broken. I can not figure out where the problem is.
https://i.imgur.com/c0DaQJI.jpg

Comment: It almost looks like it should https://datatables.net/examples/styling/bootstrap4 except some alignment issues. Consider you have the recent versions of the DT bs4 files and there not is some other hardcoded CSS that interfers. I really cannot remote debug what ever setup you have on your local machine.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I removed the css for the datatables that the theme dashboard uses and added the css from the DataTables site. Now the table is rendering correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I use the dashboard theme css that I downloaded to use in the application and it has bootstrap4 css for datatables. For some reason it was not rendering correctly. I removed the import of these css and added those from the DataTables site:

Removing:

```
<link href="{% static 'datatables.net-bs4/css/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.css' %}" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Adding:

```
<link href="{% static 'datatables/media/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css' %}" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
```

The table is now rendered correctly.

[image: DataTable rendered correctly.]